# Rudin Chapter 3 exercise 5.

Tags: analysis

I am trying to solve exercise 5, Chapter 3 of Rudin. Basically showing that the limit superior of a sum of sequences is less than or equal to the sum of the limit superiors of the individual sequences, as n tends to infinity.

> For any two real sequences $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, prove that: $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_n+B_n) \le \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(A_n) + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (B_n)$

My solution is the following:
For all n, An <= s*(a) where s*(a) is the limit superior of An as n-->inf
For all n, Bn <= s*(b) where s*(b) is the limit superior of Bn as n-->inf
So that An + Bn <= s*(a) + s*(b)

Now suppose that s*(a+b), (the limit superior of An + Bn, as n goes to inf)  is greater than s*(a) + s*(b). That means that there is an x, such that
s*(a) + s*(b) < x < s*(a+b), where x is a subsequential limit of a subsequence of An+Bn. But that means that for some n, An+Bn > s*(a) + s*(b), which is a contradiction. So that s*(a+b)<= s*(a) + s*(b).

Does that proof make sense? I looked at proofs on the net and they seem a lot more complicated.

Apologies for the formating issues.

Comment: I want to help but I don't understand what exercise is saying.  Can you state it more precisely?

Comment: Exercise is the following:

For any two real sequences {An}, {Bn}, prove that:
lim sup (An+Bn) <= lim sup (An) + lim sup (Bn) as n tends to inf.
provided that the sum on the right is not of the form +inf -inf

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof isn't quite correct.  If $A_n$ is a sequence of real numbers, it is not true that $A_m \leq \limsup\limits_n A_n$ for all $m$.  For example, $$(2.1, 1, 2.01, 1, 2.001, 1, ...)$$ has $2$ as its limit superior.

Answer (score 3):

Define $$C_k=\sup\{A_n:n≥k\}, \text { and } D_k=\sup\{B_n:n≥k\} \text{ (both of them are non-increasing)}$$

Then given any $ k$, $A_n + B_n \le C_k + D_k$, for all $n \ge k$

If we take sup for above inequality, we get ($E_k$ is also non-increasing):

$$E_k=\sup\{A_n+B_n : n \ge k\} \le C_k + D_k \text{, for all }k$$

Thus

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}E_k\le \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}C_k + \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}D_k$$

We are done, since by definition:

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}C_k,$$ $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_n=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}D_k,$$
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(A_n+B_n)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}E_k$$

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this definition of limsup. This is easier to conceive than the Rudin definition.

Comment: @GCh You are welcome. They are equivalent definitions, because $C_k$, $D_k$, $E_k$ are non-increasing sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: By definition, $\limsup (a_n)$ is the infimum of the numbers $s_k = \sup \{a_k, a_{k+1}, ... \}$ for $k \geq 1$.  Verify and make use of the following facts:

1 .  If $(s_n), (t_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are sequences of real numbers, then $\sup (s_n + t_n) \leq \sup (s_n) + \sup (t_n)$, where $(s_n + t_n)$ is the sequence $(s_1 + t_1, s_2 + t_2, ...)$.

2 .  If $(s_n), (t_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ are sequences, then $\inf(s_n + t_n) \geq \inf s_n + \inf t_n$.  If both sequences are *nonincreasing* ($s_1 \geq s_2 \geq \cdots$ and the same for $t_n$), then this is actually an equality.